# Access the SALT generated by jasypt's FixedStringSaltGenerator and setSaltGenerator?

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

I need to decrypt text in C# that was encrypted in Java using jasypt. I found and tried to use [code](https://thomashundley.com/2011/04/21/emulating-javas-pbewithmd5anddes-encryption-with-net/) that claims to emulate the jasypt process, without success. One concern I have is the SALT. The Java folks are using the FixedStringSaltGenerator, but the source for that suggests that the salt length is determined by a length property that is perhaps different than the length of the string used for the salt. The Java folks are not able to provide access to the salt that was generated by the setSaltGenerator process. Is there a way to get access to that salt?

Alternate question: is there a better way to encrypt data via Java besides the generators that would give the Java folks more control over all aspects, including the salt?

Answer (score 1):

The FixedStringSaltGenerator has a default salt size of 8 bytes. So if a salt string of "abcdefghij" is specified, only "abcdefgh" will actually be used. On the .net side, I wasn't using a generator and was simply creating a byte array, so the byte array needed to reflect the 8 character size, rather than using the entire string that the java developers claimed to use.